# Calculating average in awk based on column condition in csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, numeric-data

I have the following `csv` format. *There are vals from the whole month, but I've chunked it*:

```
2415.02,2203.35,00:17,25:May:2017,
3465.02,2203.35,01:17,25:May:2017,
2465.02,2203.35,12:17,26:May:2017,
465.02,2203.35,13:17,26:May:2017,
245.02,2203.35,14:17,26:May:2017,
2465.02,2203.35,05:17,26:May:2017,
2865.02,2203.35,06:17,27:May:2017,
2490.12,2203.35,07:17,27:May:2017,
```

I need to calculate average of the first column ($1) based on values for that day ($4). Note, that I can reformat date, if that is needed for easier calculation.

My miserable attempt was this:

```
$ awk  '{FS=","; day=$4;value+=$1} END{ print  day,value/NR}' file
27:May:2017 2109.41
```

I need output like this:

```
Average for 25th May is *average_for_25th_day*
Average for 27th May is *average_for_26th_day*
Average for 28th May is *average_for_27th_day*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

```
awk -F, '{date1[$4]+=$1;++date2[$4]}END{for (key in date1) print "Average of",key,"is",date1[key]/date2[key]}' file
Average of 27:May:2017 is 2677.57
Average of 26:May:2017 is 1410.02
Average of 25:May:2017 is 2940.02
```

Explanation:

`-F,` : Defines the delimiter . Alternatively could be `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}...`

Then we create two arrays `date1` and `date2` in which we use the 4th field `$4` as array index/key and the first field `$1` as value added to the existed value of the same array position.

So for the first row we would have

`date1[27:May:2017]+=2415.02`
`++date2[27:May:2017]` --> increases the value by 1 --> value 1 for first line

For the next same date  (line 2) we would have

`date1[27:May:2017]+=2415.02 + 3465.02`
`++date2[27:May:2017]` --> increases the value by 1 --> value 2 (second line)

Same logic extends to all the lines having the same date and also to all different dates.

At the end , we use a `for` loop to iterate through the keys of array `date1` (or `date2` - keys are the same in both arrays => `$4`) and for every `key` found we print the `key` (=the date $4) and we also print the `date1[key]` value = sum of all `$1` values for the same date `$4`, divided by `date2[key]` value = numeric count of the lines found having the same date = same `$4`.

Comment: Awesome, mind explain a bit? Thanks!!

Comment: @fugitive Explanation added

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant, using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to do the averaging:

```
datamash -t, groupby 4 mean 1 < file | 
  awk -F'[,:]' '{printf "Average for %dth %s is %f\n", $1,$2,$4}'
Average for 25th May is 2940.020000
Average for 26th May is 1410.020000
Average for 27th May is 2677.570000
```

Comment: That's an amazing tool!